# Aggregate column values into a list produces an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query

```
DECLARE @SNH TABLE 
(
    dt date, 
    QueueName varchar(10),
    SN varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @SNH (Dt, QueueName, SN)
VALUES ('2001-04-04', 'Queue01', 'Q01SN01'),
       ('2001-04-05', 'Queue01', 'Q01SN01'),
       ('2001-04-06', 'Queue01', 'Q01SN01'),
       ('2001-04-04', 'Queue02', 'Q02SN01'),
       ('2001-04-05', 'Queue02', 'Q02SN01'),
       ('2001-04-06', 'Queue02', 'Q02SN02')

DECLARE @QH TABLE 
(
    DT date, 
    QueueName varchar(10)
)  

INSERT INTO @QH(DT, QueueName)
VALUES ('2001-04-04','Queue01'),
       ('2001-04-05','Queue01'),
       ('2001-04-06','Queue01'),
       ('2001-04-04','Queue02'),
       ('2001-04-05','Queue02'),
       ('2001-04-06','Queue02')

SELECT DISTINCT 
    q.QueueName clnQueueName,
    MIN(q.Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName) clnStartDate,
    MAX(q.Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName) clnEndDate,
    s.SN
FROM 
    @QH q
LEFT JOIN 
    @SNH s ON s.QueueName = q.QueueName
```

returns this output:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| clnQueueName | clnStartDate | clnEndDate | SN |
| Queue01 | 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Q01SN01 |
| Queue02 | 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Q02SN01 |
| Queue02 | 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Q02SN02 |

which I'm aiming to aggregate into a comma separated list with

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    q.QueueName clnQueueName,
    MIN(q.Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName) clnStartDate,
    MAX(q.Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY q.QueueName) clnEndDate,
    STRING_AGG(s.SN,',')
FROM 
    @QH q
LEFT JOIN 
    @SNH s ON s.QueueName = q.QueueName AND s.Dt = q.Dt
```

as follows

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| clnQueueName | clnStartDate | clnEndDate | SN |
| Queue01 | 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Q01SN01 |
| Queue02 | 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Q02SN01,Q02SN02 |

Instead I get:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
> Column '@QH.QueueName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Sorry, I can't get it.

`@QH.QueueName` isn't even mentioned in the `SELECT`, only `q.QueueName`.

What I am missing here?

Comment: `@QH.QueueName` **IS** `q.QueueName` because you have alised `@QH` to `q`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), a `group by` clause is required if the `string_agg` is not the only item being selected. Once grouping correctly you no longer need window functions or `distinct`.

To obtain only distinct values of `SN` you need to group twice, the first time in a sub-query (in this case a CTE) to get distinct values of `SN` and the second time with `string_agg` to get distinct values of `QueueName`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        q.QueueName clnQueueName
        , MIN(q.Dt) clnStartDate
        , MAX(q.Dt) clnEndDate
        , s.SN
    FROM @QH q
    LEFT JOIN @SNH s
        ON s.QueueName = q.QueueName AND s.Dt = q.Dt
    GROUP BY q.QueueName, s.SN
)
SELECT clnQueueName
    , MIN(clnStartDate) clnStartDate
    , MAX(clnEndDate) clnEndDate
    , STRING_AGG(SN,',') SN
FROM cte
GROUP BY clnQueueName;
```

Returns:

| clnQueueName | clnStartDate | clnEndDate | SN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Queue01 | 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Q01SN01 |
| Queue02 | 2001-04-04 | 2001-04-06 | Q02SN01,Q02SN02 |

Comment: Thank you, Dale! Would you care to hint how to distinct aggregate results?

Comment: I probably didn't make myself clear enough.

Comment: Q02SN01,Q02SN01,Q02SN02 -> Q02SN01,Q02SN02. This is what I meant

Comment: the right answer's query's last column contains the same values for Queue01 which are 'Q01SN01,Q01SN01,Q01SN01'. How would you filter them out to leave just unique values? For the 2nd row that would be 'Q02SN01,Q02SN02' instead of 'Q02SN01,Q02SN01,Q02SN02'

Comment: they are there, in the @SNH table. The correct query (your query) should be run against the data. Would it be the right thing to update the question with your query?

Comment: No, try my answer now

Comment: Thank you! Your updated answer didn't compile right away, but I got the idea. It's again me to blame for not saying exactly what the goal actually is. Let me try again, please. Your first query produces almost exactly what I'm looking for. This first query (without cte) gives us 2 rows and in the last column there are SN values separated by comma. Is there a way to have in the last column just unique values? Take a look at the 2nd row. It is now  Queue02,2001-04-04,2001-04-06,'Q02SN01,Q02SN01,Q02SN02'. The goal is to have it as follows Queue02,2001-04-04,2001-04-06,'Q02SN01,Q02SN02'

Comment: ";" before WITH, alias to s.SN in the cte and that was it! It's 4:50am in Moscow and I can finally to go sleep! Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually the ';' goes at the end of the previous statement - you should always terminate all SQL statements with ';'.

Comment: you are right, as always! I learned a lot today. Thank you!

Comment: Afterthoughts. Would you please tell me how do you 1) format the errors 2) format variables 3) tables ? For tables I use https://donatstudios.com/CsvToMarkdownTable, but the Headers are not that neat as in your replies

Comment: Edit the question and answer to see the markdown (and then cancel the edit). In fact the editor does also tell you how